# How to fix tensorflow TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python Scalars

Tags: tensorflow

I was using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/python/label_image.py) to test my [tflite](https://github.com/alyaananda/tflite/blob/main/yolov3-int8-2.tflite)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "label_image.py", line 124, in <module>
    print('{:08.6f}: {}'.format(float(results[i]), labels[i]))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I'm quite a newbie in using Tensorflow so any help is much appreciated

Edit 1 : I forgot to include the [label](https://github.com/alyaananda/tflite/blob/main/obj.txt) and image [sample](https://github.com/alyaananda/tflite/blob/main/Damsi_001.jpg)

Edit 2 : I tried debugging by print(results[i]) and this is the result

```
[[27.572786   2.910608  39.202885   4.485999 ]
[19.35345    2.12116   22.764465   5.368863 ]
[ 2.664798   2.9718513 11.22389   11.967384 ]
[11.17787    1.9934689 13.393661   8.419806 ]]
```

And I still have no idea what is happening

Comment: are you trying to print that array? or is this supposed to be a single number (scalar)

Comment: The problem is that results[i] is a array/matrix, and you are trying to convert this to float (a scalar), which triggers the error. This should be enough for you to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This errors means that something in your code is trying to interpret or convert a tensor as/to a single float but the tensor is not of size 1. A "tensor of size-1" means that it only contains one single float.

Here is an example of size-1 tensor:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.constant([1.0])

print(data.shape)
```

This prints `(1,)` which tells that `data` has only one dimension and only one element along that dimension.

Here is an example of a tensor not of size-1:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

data = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(data.shape)
```

this prints `(2, 2)` which means that `data` is a two dimensional tensor (a matrix) of size 2 by 2.

---

The issue in your code is probably in the expression `float(results[i])`. This will fail if `result[i]` is not a size-1 tensor. You should debug this expression, for instance by printing its contents of shape.

Comment: I edited the original post to include the result[i]. It seems that mine is not size-1 and i dont know how to deal with this

Comment: This look a lot like a tensor of bounding boxes coordinates, which are tensors of shape `(4,)` (four coordinates). If this is the case, then you should change your print statement to log the door coordinates. For instance you could simply do `print("{}: {}".format(results[i], labels[i]))`.